# Solr search by text

Tags: apache, search, solr

I have a problem searching a document in Solr by a query.

The document looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "890_03366_00739",
  "text": ["2509412 MARCO GLLMRC86E28L736X  03366 00739 "],
  "_version_": 1612212288969769000
}
```

If i search with query `text:GLLMRC86E28L736` i found correctly the document.
If i try with query `text:GLLMRC86E28L736X` i can't find the document, why this happens?

In my schema the field `text` is declared as `<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>`

I'm using Solr 7.0.0.

**UPDATE**:

The "Analysis" page shows this output for my field "text" and query GLLMRC86E28L736X

[image: query GLLMRC86E28L736X]

For query GLLMRC86E28L736
[image: query GLLMRC86E28L736]

Search by GLLMRC86E28L736X
[image: search 1]
Search by GLLMRC86E28L736
[image: search 2]
The field type "text_general" is declared as

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="2"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Comment: According to the details you've posted, it should work as you expect. What does the "analysis" page under the core show for the given field type, given the indexed text and your query?

Comment: I added the analysis and print screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EdgeNgramFilter has a `maxGramSize` setting that cuts off the ending of the token - the X is dropped when indexing, while it's kept when querying (as it should, if you're attempting to match prefixes).

On the left side of the analysis screen you can see that it generates versions of `GLLMRC86E28L736X`, but the last character is dropped - i.e. it stops generating versions before adding the last one. The query is still `GLLMRC86E28L736X`, and since there is no token matching `GLLMRC86E28L736X` (only `GLLMRC86E28L736` since it stopped after generating that), you get no hit.

Adjust the `maxGramSize` for your field, or search against a field that doesn't do any edgengramming if you want to get exact matches only.

In addition, this is not the default form for the `text_general` field type included in the examples if I remember correctly, so in the future it'll be helpful if you include the field type as well.

Comment: In "index" analyzer the maxGramSize on EdgeNGramFilterFactory is set to 15, in "query" analyzer there's no EdgeNGramFilterFactory filter. Should i edit something?

Comment: Yes, since maxGramSize is set to `15`, and `GLLMRC86E28L736X` has 16 characters, anything after `15` is chopped off. If you want to keep all tokens regardless of size, set `maxGramSize` to the length of the longest token (or just 32768 if you don't know what the longest is and you still want to generate tokens up to the max size). If you don't need prefix searches, remove the edge ngram filter.

Comment: It works, thanks. The only problem is that I need to reindex whole core.